# Open API documentation of Springboot based REST apis fail with ApplicationContextException. The project is built with gradlew shadow plugins

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc-openapi-ui, gradle-shadow-plugin

I am trying to add open api documentation to springboot base REST api project that I have.
It works fine when run locally inside intelliJ IDE or with gradlew run/bootRun

But when the project is packaged as a fat jar using gradlew shadow plugin 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' and run on command line as `java -jar build/libs/Application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-all.jar` it fails with `ApplicationContextException`

Exception stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:205) ~[Application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-all.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:177) ~[Application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-all.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158) ~[Application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-all.jar:?]
        ... 9 more
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version "6.0.0"
}
application {
    mainClassName = 'com.example.Application'
    executableDir = 'lib/'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.12'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation files( "lib/$JarV2" )
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.3.3.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.4.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.14.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.14.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.14.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.30'
    implementation 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    implementation "com.moandjiezana.toml:toml4j:0.7.2"
    implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:$jwtVersion"
    runtimeOnly "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:$jwtVersion"
    runtimeOnly "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:$jwtVersion"
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.18.1'
    implementation 'com.auth0:jwks-rsa:0.19.0'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Without the openapi dependency
`implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.12'`

standalone run `java -jar build/libs/Application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-all.jar` works absolutely fine.

Is there some dependency conflict between open api and springboot libs ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be known issue and can be solved by including following in build.gradle

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.*

shadowJar {

zip64 true

exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'

// Required for Spring
mergeServiceFiles()
transform(AppendingTransformer) { resource = 'reference.conf'  }
transform(AppendingTransformer) { resource = 'META-INF/spring.handlers'  }
transform(AppendingTransformer) { resource = 'META-INF/spring.schemas'  }
transform(AppendingTransformer) { resource = 'META-INF/spring.tooling'  }
transform(PropertiesFileTransformer) {
    paths = ['META-INF/spring.factories' ]
    mergeStrategy = "append"
}
}
```

source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1828